# Why JWT Expires too fast

Tags: c#

I set JWT expires to 3 hours, but it expires too early (below 2 minutes)

```cs
string _keys = JWT.Key;
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_keys));
var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
double _minutes = Security.Minute_JWT_Expiry;

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(JWT.Issuer, JWT.Key,
  null,
  expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(180),
  signingCredentials: credentials);

return await Task.FromResult(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
```

Comment: You should also include the code which determines when a JWT expires.

Comment: My bet is on comparing `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(180)` to local DST.

Comment: users was kicked when calling a method which has the [Authorize] option, like below:
        
        
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
         public async Task<Tuple<Models.User_Data, Models.Response>> 
        Change_Password([FromBody]Models.Change_Password _request)

Comment: Take the JWT and decode it from base64 and then read the payload. Are the `IAT` and `EXP` values set as expected? If they are correct then the problem lies when the JWT is validated. If not then the problem lies when the JWT is generated. This site might be of help: https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 0):

just want to share:
this problem because I compare value with DateTime.Now.. it should be like below:

```
  if (expires.HasValue)
      return expires.Value > DateTime.UtcNow;
```

complete:

```
  var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JWT.Key);
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidIssuer = JWT.Issuer,
                    LifetimeValidator =
                    (before, expires, token, parameters) =>
                    {
                       if (before.HasValue && before.Value > DateTime.Now)
                            return false;

                        if (expires.HasValue)
                            return expires.Value > DateTime.UtcNow;

                        //Otherwise the token is valid
                        return true;
                    },
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                };
            });
```